# Declarar variable escalar en Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Tengo el siguiente SP y me marca el siguiente error en el SP:

> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 137 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@Hoy". SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 8180 Error = [Microsoft][SQL
>   Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be
>   prepared.
>
> Must declare the scalar variable

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE consulta_diaria2
@Hoy DATE
AS
BEGIN


SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @Hoy = GETDATE()
-- Insert statements for procedure here
--DECLARE @archivo varchar(50)

DECLARE @comando varchar(2000)
DECLARE @query   VARCHAR(2000)


SET @query   = 'bcp "SELECT c.CodeCompany, @Hoy AS fechaActual, a.idClave, c.nombre +''-''+c.apellidos AS Nombre,d.Descripcion AS Depto,t.HorasAlDia AS HorasDia,convert(time(0),fechaEntrada) AS Entrada,convert(time(0),fechaSalida) AS Salida,DATEDIFF(HOUR,fechaEntrada,fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia FROM tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave JOIN tblTurno t ON t.idTurno=c.fkTurno JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto WHERE fechaEntrada BETWEEN @Hoy AND DATEADD(DAY,1,@Hoy) and fkStatus !=1" queryout E:\archivo.txt -c -T'


SET @comando = @query  + ' -Usa -P123456'



EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @comando


END
GO
```

Comment: Considero que noo tiene caso que recibas la variable `@Hoy` como parámetro si después vas a asignarle un valor.

Comment: @Flxtr es decir la tengo que declarar desde despues de BEGIN así: CREATE PROCEDURE consulta_diaria2
 
AS
BEGINDECLARE Hoy DATE
 SELECT Hoy = GETDATE()

Comment: Si lo hago de esa forma, al ejecutar el SP me marca: Procedure consulta_diaria2 has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Comment: @NoelL pues significa que debes llamar el procedure sin enviarle argumentos...

Answer (score 0):

Modifica esta linea en el `set @query`

```
SET @query   = 'bcp "SELECT c.CodeCompany, ' + @Hoy +' AS fechaActual, a.idClave, c.nombre +''-''+c.apellidos AS Nombre,d.Descripcion AS Depto,t.HorasAlDia AS HorasDia,convert(time(0),fechaEntrada) AS Entrada,convert(time(0),fechaSalida) AS Salida,DATEDIFF(HOUR,fechaEntrada,fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia FROM tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave JOIN tblTurno t ON t.idTurno=c.fkTurno JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto WHERE fechaEntrada BETWEEN ' +  @Hoy + ' AND DATEADD(DAY,1, ' + @Hoy + ' ) and fkStatus !=1" queryout E:\archivo.txt -c -T'
```

Comment: Creo que eso no lo resolvería, ya que eso tendría como salida algo así: `bcp "SELECT c.CodeCompany, 2017-01-15 AS fechaActual, a.idClave,`

Comment: El error es colocando `@Hoy` como valor; puede colocar `getdate()`  y se resolvería también.

Comment: @BiancoVidalSaavedra Puede ser que sea relacionado en como estoy pasando Hoy, ya que colocandolo como dices me muestra: The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: @BiancoVidalSaavedra cuando coloco getdate() muestra lo siguiente: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Esto es otro error, ejecuta esto:
`SET @query   = 'bcp "SELECT c.CodeCompany, ' + @Hoy +' AS fechaActual, a.idClave, c.nombre +''-''+c.apellidos AS Nombre,d.Descripcion AS Depto,t.HorasAlDia AS HorasDia, convert(char(8), fechaEntrada, 108) as Entrada,convert(char(8), fechaSalida, 108) as Salida,DATEDIFF(HOUR,fechaEntrada,fechaSalida) % 24 AS horasAlDia FROM tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave JOIN tblTurno t ON t.idTurno=c.fkTurno JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto WHERE fechaEntrada BETWEEN ' +  @Hoy + ' AND DATEADD(DAY,1, ' + @Hoy + ' ) and fkStatus !=1"'`

Answer (score 0):

El problema se da debido a que la variable `@query` no tiene forma de saber cómo se puede estar concatenando la variable `@hoy` y además ésta está fuera de su contexto actual. Para resolverlo tendrás que modificar la variable `@query` y usando directamente la función `GETDATE()`:

```
SET @query   = 'bcp "SELECT c.CodeCompany, GETDATE() AS fechaActual, a.idClave, c.nombre +''-''+c.apellidos AS Nombre,d.Descripcion AS Depto,t.HorasAlDia AS HorasDia,convert(time(0),fechaEntrada) AS Entrada,convert(time(0),fechaSalida) AS Salida,DATEDIFF(HOUR,fechaEntrada,fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia FROM tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave JOIN tblTurno t ON t.idTurno=c.fkTurno JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto WHERE fechaEntrada BETWEEN @Hoy AND DATEADD(DAY,1,@Hoy) and fkStatus !=1" queryout E:\archivo.txt -c -T'
```

El código completo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE consulta_diaria2
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @comando VARCHAR(2000)
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(2000)

    SET @query   = 'bcp "SELECT c.CodeCompany, GETDATE() AS fechaActual, a.idClave, c.nombre +''-''+c.apellidos AS Nombre,d.Descripcion AS Depto,t.HorasAlDia AS HorasDia,convert(time(0),fechaEntrada) AS Entrada,convert(time(0),fechaSalida) AS Salida,DATEDIFF(HOUR,fechaEntrada,fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia FROM tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave JOIN tblTurno t ON t.idTurno=c.fkTurno JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto WHERE fechaEntrada BETWEEN @Hoy AND DATEADD(DAY,1,@Hoy) and fkStatus !=1" queryout E:\archivo.txt -c -T'
    SET @comando = @query + ' -Usa -P123456'

    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @comando
END
GO
```